# Reference request: Schauder estimates for parabolic equations

Tags: reference-request, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, regularity

Where can I find Schauder estimates for second order linear parabolic equations (in divergence form with potential)?

Any reference would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the book "Elliptic and Parabolic Equations" of Z. Wu, J. Yin and C. Wang, Theorem 7.2.24.